# Gingerbread compatability for an app developed in ICS environment

Tags: android

Suppose Im developing an app in the ICS environment and in manifest I have given minSdkVersion as gingerbread, will I be able to use fragments ? I understand fragments start from Honeycomb only. Will I be able to use the Fragment api's or will they be deprecated because of my minSdkVersion ? If it us supported, then how will I be able to view it on a 2.3 device ? In short, how do I make sure that an app developed in ICS works on Gingerbread too ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fragments in pre v11 you need to use compatibility library.

[Fragments for all blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html)

Comment: Like @EvilDuck says: use the Compatibility Library. Additionally, if you want full ActionBar support, look for [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).